# How to receive an endless WebSocket data source using AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-lambda

I want to crawl data from a WebSocket data source, usually WebSocket data is an endless stream, while an AWS Lambda function has a Timout limit, the maximum allowed value is 900 seconds.

If my Lambda function acts as a WebSocket client and connects to a WebSocket url, e.g., `wss://ws-feed-public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com`, it starts to receive data for 900 seconds and get terminated by then.

How to keep my Lamda function running forever? Thanks!

Right now I'm running my crawler inside a Linux VM, is it possible to migrate it to AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Lambda functions run for a **maximum of 900 seconds** (15 minutes).

There is no way to extend this.

You should continue using an Amazon EC2 instance or a container (ECS, Fargate).

**Fun fact:** When initially released, the limit was 3 minutes. It was later extended to 5 minutes, then to 15 minutes.

Comment: Got it, VM or container is the only option, thanks!

Comment: How would I do this using fargate? do you have any examples? thanks a ton!